# Change the default scroll bar in all cross browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, polymer

Is their any element in polymer that is used for custom scroll bar styles for all browsers(changing default scroll and add my own scroll bar).

How can I do this? I am using to change the scroll bar of paper-header-panel.

Comment: Scroll bars are drawn by the operating systems and browsers. You do not have much to do with CSS to change those. It is possible to implement a scroll bar with JS and CSS to set `overflow: hidden` on the scroll wrapper and then draw a scroll using css and manipulate it's position using JS. It's a bit heavy and should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is currently not possible. Try to use a jQuery library for example [Perfect Scrollbar](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar).

What this script does is hiding the OS-generated default scrollbar and drawing a new one using CSS, so you can freely customise it. I prefer Perfect Scrollbar because it doesn't mess up your DOM, it simply animates your overflown element. There are some known bugs though, so before you use it for production, please check the according forum.